# Error sql when saving date

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using query `INSERT INTO` but I found this message in Network/preview (chrome)

> Error: INSERT INTO indisponible (id_formateur,date_debut,date_fin) VALUES ( 0, 2017-04-06 , 2017-04-13)
>   Incorrect date value: '2007' for column 'date_debut' at row 1

this is my code php:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-type');

 $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
    $request = json_decode($postdata); 
    $id = $request->id;
    $debut = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->debut));
    $fin = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->fin));


$servername = "localhost"; 
$username = "root";
$password = ""; 
$dbname = "planni";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO indisponible (id_formateur,date_debut,date_fin)
VALUES ( $id, $debut , $fin)";
$conn->query($sql);

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "ajouté avec succé !";
} else { 
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Strings needs to be quoted. `VALUES ( $id, $debut , $fin)";` should be `VALUES ( $id, '$debut' , '$fin')";` - or just learn how to use parameterized queries, and you'll never have that problem.

Comment: Get rid of the SQL injection vulnerability and the problem becomes moot.  SQL prepared statements and query parameters aren't just about security, they're also about stable and maintainable code.

Comment: it's working now like this: VALUES ( $id, '$debut' , '$fin')";